# entityManager The Data was change often

Tags: entitymanager

I'm using entityManager to operate the database. But in my project, I get a problem like this: when I update the data, then findPage to show the data. I got the data was update before Or update after. the two status was appear alternately. How can I fix this problem?

I have change the dataSource
set spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.isolation=2
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

```
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends BaseEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> implements BaseDao<T, ID> {

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public void persist(T entity) {
   Assert.notNull(entity);
   entityManager.persist(entity);
}

public T merge(T entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity);
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}

protected Page<T> findPage(CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery, Pageable pageable) {
    Assert.notNull(criteriaQuery);
    Assert.notNull(criteriaQuery.getSelection());
    Assert.notEmpty(criteriaQuery.getRoots());
    if (pageable == null) {
        pageable = new Pageable();
    }
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        Root<T> root = getRoot(criteriaQuery);
        addRestrictions(criteriaQuery, pageable);
        addOrders(criteriaQuery, pageable);
        if (criteriaQuery.getOrderList().isEmpty()) {
            if (OrderEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(entityClass)) {
                criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(OrderEntity.ORDER_PROPERTY_NAME)));
            } else if (BaseEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(entityClass)) {
                criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(BaseEntity.CREATE_DATE_PROPERTY_NAME)));
            }
        }

        long total = 0;
        // TODO 分组之后记录总数
        if (!pageable.getGroupby()) {
            total = count(criteriaQuery, null);
        }
        int totalPages = (int) Math.ceil((double) total / (double) pageable.getPageSize());
        if (totalPages < pageable.getPageNumber()) {
            pageable.setPageNumber(totalPages);
        }
        TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        query.setFirstResult((pageable.getPageNumber() - 1) * pageable.getPageSize());
        query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
        return new Page<T>(query.getResultList(), total, pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing persistence context after data modification? `entityManager.flush()`

Comment: No, I don't call entityManager.flush();

Comment: I mean try this and tell me, if it helps :)

Comment: But, I have another project use the same BaseDaoImpl and it's run well. i build the new project and use it's BaseDaoImpl module  and get the problem as I post.

Comment: it doesn't work! it will auto flush when it commit. And If I tried entityManager.clear() before findPage, it will return the correct data everytime. But I think this way was not a good choice.